# subdivide web api authorization in machine to machine scenario

Tags: identityserver3

I need advice coming up with the proper configuration for a scenario using IdentiyServer.

The scenario is machine to machine communication.  A single web api is divided into two parts.  One part allows notifications to be posted into it (write).  The second allows information to be queried from it (read).

I envision protecting endpoints with something like `[Authorize("Write")]` and `[Authorize("Read")]`.  From what I can tell, scopes are API wide... if they can be used to clarify access in this way, I haven't figured it out... or its too simple for my brain.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scopes can be used at a finer grained level than app wide. Just do a normal claims check in the API for the scope you require for that API.

Perhaps even something like this would work: https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/blob/master/source/WebApi.ScopeAuthorization/ScopeAuthorizeAttribute.cs

Comment: It turns out using an authorization manager to enable ResourceAuthorize was the best route for my needs.  Thanks.